# pass object to factorygirl rspec

Tags: rspec-rails, rspec3

I am using rails 5 and rspec 3.6.0. I have 3 models User, Organization and UserOrganization. An user can belong to multiple organizations. We maintain an association to the 'current_organization' which is the user's current logged in organization.
I have defined the factory for user as

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email { FFaker::Internet.email }

    factory :admin_with_organization do
      after(:build) do |user|
        org = create :organization
        org_user = build(:organization_user, organization: org, user: user)
        org_user.add_role :administrator
        user.current_organization = org
        user.current_role = org_user.roles.first
      end
    end

    factory :doctor_with_organization do
      after(:build) do |user|
        org = create :organization
        org_user = build(:organization_user, organization: org, user: user)
        org_user.add_role :doctor
        user.current_organization = org
        user.current_role = org_user.roles.first
      end
    end

    ...
 end
```

Is there a way where in an organization object can be passed to the above factories so that all multiple users belonging to the same organization can be created?

Comment: I would just make an `:organization_with_users` factory.

Comment: @MikeSchutte thats not what I meant. I want to create multiple users for the same organization with having the choice to create the type of user.